# scroll view by image view ios

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I create `scrollView` in `viewController` with zero constraints and after I added an `imageView` of same size and I give that `imageView` size to `equal width and heights` with `scrollView` after I give height priority 250 `scrollView` is working perfect when I was scrolling the `imageView` on top and bottom its preview is white space.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check Your Top Constraints of imageView its bind with SuperView OR
   Safe Area?? if its bind with Safe Area then change with SuperView..
   see below image for more information

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJfJv.png]